# DecisionTree Selector in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, decision-tree, dropdownbox, multipleselection

I am trying to find a smart way to create a multi-level decision tree selector in angularjs. So, basically what I am looking for is:
If I select Maingroup "GroupA" from a dropdown list, than I should only see the properties from subgroup1 related to GroupA. The subgroup1 should be also a dropdownlist. Then, refining the selection by another dropdownlist, should display only the possible selections based on Maingroup+Subgroup1.
Finally, the value should be displayed.

```
[{"Maingroup":"GroupA","Subgroup1":"subgroupA1","Subgroup2":"subgroupA21","Value":11.34},
{"Maingroup":"GroupA","Subgroup1":"subgroupA1","Subgroup2":"subgroupA22","Value":40.7},
{"Maingroup":"GroupA","Subgroup1":"subgroupA2","Subgroup2":"subgroupA23","Value":58.23},
{"Maingroup":"GroupA","Subgroup1":"subgroupA2","Subgroup2":"subgroupA24","Value":20.64},
{"Maingroup":"GroupA","Subgroup1":"subgroupA2","Subgroup2":"subgroupA25","Value":74.77},
```

I have put a screenshot and the json file on [github](https://github.com/robertodijo/DecisionTree).
Thanks, any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [angular-ui-tree connected trees demo](http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/connected-trees). The structure can be reused to achieve your goals.